# how to call package import only knowing file name

Tags: perl

th_foo.pm

```
package Foo;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = 'foo';

sub foo { print "foo\n"; }
sub bar { print "bar\n"; }

1;
```

Case 1

main.pl

```
use lib '.';

delete $INC{ 'th_foo.pm' };
require 'th_foo.pm';
'Foo'->import();

foo();
```

Result

```
$ perl main.pl
foo
```

Case 2

main.pl

```
use lib '.';

delete $INC{ 'th_foo.pm' };
require 'th_foo.pm';
'th_foo.pm'->import();

foo();
```

Result

```
$ perl main.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::foo called at th.pl line 9.
```

Question

Can we call Foo's import method by only knowing the file name, th_foo.pm, and not knowing the package name, Foo?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the packages used by an executed file.

You could scan the symbol table beforehand and afterwards and check for differences, but that will also include symbols created by modules used by the file you are executing.

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the *th_foo.pm* file, you can use the last evaluated expression to pass back information through the `require`. This only works the first time you `require` the file in a program, but you're already playing the `%INC`.

```
package Foo;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = 'foo';

sub foo { print "foo\n"; }
sub bar { print "bar\n"; }

__PACKAGE__;
```

Then, in the program:

```
my $package = require 'th_foo.pm';
$package->import;
```

Again, this is fragile because you must be the first `require` on that file (otherwise it just returns a boolean). But, in one case I have done something like this, which is sure to get you a beating in code review:

```
sub my_require ( $file ) {
   state %cache;
   my $rc = require $file;
   $cache{$file} //= $rc;
   }
```

I do this for all of my *Makefile.PL* files in my Perl dists ([example in object-iterate](https://github.com/briandfoy/object-iterate/blob/master/Makefile.PL)). When I want to process all of my distributions to do something (like, which ones have a minimum version of v5.8?), I `require` the *Makefile.PL* and know which package I'm dealing with (although the repo path works too but needs more work).

Curiously, there is a suggestion that we should remove the true value from the end of Perl modules. David Farrell wrote about it in [Patching Perl: loading modules that return false](https://www.perl.com/article/patching-perl-loading-modules-that-return-false/) and it's now [an issue for Perl 7](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17921). This doesn't affect the return value though; it just doesn't complain if you return false or empty. It knows it failed through other means.

Comment: Re "*This only works the first time you require the file*", If that's an issue, it's because you're using `require` when you should be using `do`.